# Connecting Azure AD to Cloud Cloud

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, entra-id

So I am currently using Azure AD and using Azure itself as a whole. 
I use Azure to do the following:

- Host the web application (It's written in .NETCore)
- Blob storage
- Azure functions
- DevOps

I use Google Cloud to do the following:

- MySQL (I find it cheap)
- Firestore
- Google Maps API's

I want to be able to sign in with my Office 365 email and also assign and restrict user's from accessing certain project and etc...

How can I set this up?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Based on my assumption you are asking about configuring Azure AD for SSO. If so, you could refer to this [documentaion](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on#configuring_azure_ad_for_single_sign-on). Or if you are talking about the how your users can use Google cloud credential to sign in to enterprise-cloud application. Refer to [this doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6363817?hl=en).

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to use my Azure AD, to manage and use google cloud apps